# Is there a limited bandwidth for the Dropbox API (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, api, dropbox, bandwidth, limits

I want to store audio files of a podcast in my Dropbox for showcasing them on a smaller static Website.

So far I tried using public links to each file, but reach the bandwidth limit of these quite fast, because everytime somebody reloads the page that takes around 500 MB.

I thought about using the Dropbox API for accessing the files, but are there the same limits for the API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no, you can try contacting their support team.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox links have bandwidth limits. You can find more information here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/4204

This does not apply to authenticated (non-link) access though. For example, downloading files via dropbox.com or via the API [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download). That probably isn't a great solution though, as it requires an access token. You may be better served by a normal CDN.